# SQL Server backup compression vs 7zip

Tags: sql-server

Moving to SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition from 2008 Standard Edition, I was hoping to ditch my scripts that use 7z to compress backups in favor of built-in backup compression.

I find that the SQL Server compression backup files are approximately twice as big as uncompressed then 7zip-ed backup files.

I have to move the compressed files over a slow connection, so 2x is significant.

Is there anything I can do to improve the compression ratio for SQL Server's built-in compressed backups?

Comment: Commenting on an old question so it may no longer be relevant to you, but if you are updating off-site copies regularly over the slow link you could try use rsync or similar to create the new instance by updating a copy of the last one. SQL Server does not do "treat the data as a single stream" compression so rsync can sometimes still make significant bandwidth savings when dealing with backups compressed that way (unlike those compressed with 7zip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Not natively anyway  The options for backup compression are "Use it" or "Don't Use It".  There's no way to set compression levels or anything like that.  To get better control you need to use a third party compression tool.

Comment: If you just wait long enough, you likely will see compression options and more efficient algorithms appear in later releases of SQL Server. How could anybody in the software industry make the big bucks if software were well-thought-out from version 1?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the other answer (up to this point this is) there is not much you can do besides make a decision on the matter.

If you are having second thoughts on the basis that the built in compression system might somehow be more reliable (or superior in some other way) to just 7z-ing the backups, you can do this:

Continue as you were, moving 7z-ed backups over the low B/W link AND produce compressed backups with the built in system that you can always store locally, in case something goes wrong.